# Apache fails to start, Address already in use (but not really)

Tags: 12.04, apache2, virtualization

I'm trying to set up a VM running Ubuntu 12.04. I have two virtual hosts configured using port 80, but Apache will not start.

I get this error:
`(98) Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80`

The output of `netstat -tulpn` shows that nothing is using port 80. What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: are you starting it as root? By default only root can open ports below 1024.

Comment: Yes, I am. It was running at one point when I had just one virtual host configured, so I've since removed the other virtual host to try to remedy the issue, but no luck with that either.

Comment: Does you host have something running on port 80 and you're in bridged mode for the guest?  I don't know that it would do that, but it seems probable

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions from [Starting apache fails (could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80)](http://askubuntu.com/q/122200/88802)? And please also include the output of `grep -ri listen /etc/apache` and `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 80`.

Comment: `grep -ri listen /etc/apache2` outputs: 
    etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Listen 80  
    /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Listen 443  
    /etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 80  
    /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:     Listen 443
    /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:     Listen 443  

`sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 80` outputs nothing at all.

Comment: This error appear also if you have defined twice or more Listen xx port ... in this case Listen 80

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out. I had duplicate Listen 80 commands in both my httpd.conf and ports.conf

Also, in copying the config file over for that server that's being virtualized, I neglected to notice that the error log directory had been changed. Looking into that error log, I noticed that the directory for the `mime.types` config file was incorrect in my `httpd.conf` file. I updated that parameter, and the server started up fine.

Comment: I also had duplicate `Listen 80` commands in both my `httpd.conf` and `ports.conf`

Answer (score 50):

Make sure you are not declaring `Listen 80` twice in .conf files.

For example, you might have it both in `ports.conf` and inn `sites-enabled/www.conf`.

To find out, use: `grep -ri listen /etc/apache2`

Keep `Listen 80` in just a single place.

Answer (score 41):

Answering the way I solved out this issue. May be helpful to someone in future.

Try `netstat -ltnp | grep :80`

This would return something like

> tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 1047/apache2

Then run

```
sudo kill -9 1047
```

Where 1047 is the pid of the program running on port 80.You can replace the pid that you obtained from `netstat`

Comment: wow!... and here i am 48 hours after sending a ticket to inmotionhosting and waiting for a reply. thank you

Comment: What does this mean? I'm not getting a PID or name. `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -    `

Comment: @AaronFranke Can you please try running this command in Terminal after maximising the window?

Comment: @AaronFranke run it with sudo. You might not have the permissions to view.

Comment: Thank you! Years later, but your solution really saved me!

Answer (score 21):

I had a Nginx server listening on my AWS EC2 server, I think it got configured when I was building the EC2, hence was I getting Address already in use error. So I stopped the service and started the Apache2 service:

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service apache2 start
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! After all tries this worked for me.

Comment: Had the same issue in a preconfigured LAMP on Digital Ocean

Comment: i remember only install apache2, and skip this answer. then trying ohter answer, but none working. but when i try this answer. its working now. thankyou

Answer (score 15):

**I got this error on a fresh install when starting apache2 Ubuntu 12.10.**

It's a bug in the apache2.  It gets hung in the background.  Here is my walkthrough to where the bugs might be in the software.

Here's the error I got:

```
el@titan:~$ sudo service apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2               
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                         [fail]
```

Address already in Use?  What could be using it?  Check it out:

```
el@titan:~$ grep -ri listen /etc/apache2
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections, and which
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:# Include list of ports to listen on and which to use for name based vhosts
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:Listen 80
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:    Listen 443
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:    Listen 443
```

That means apache2 is preventing apache2 from starting.  Bizarre.  This will confirm:

```
el@titan:~$ ps -ef | grep apache2
root      1146   954  0 15:51 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /etc/rc2.d/S91apache2 start
root      1172  1146  0 15:51 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/sbin/apache2ctl start
root      1181  1172  0 15:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      1193  1181  0 15:51 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash /usr/share/apache2/ask-for-passphrase 127.0.1.1:443 RSA
el        5439  5326  0 16:23 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto apache2
```

Yes, in this case apache2 is running, I was trying to start apache2 a second time on the same port.

What confuses me is that `service` reports that apache2 is NOT running:

```
el@titan:~$ sudo service apache2 status
Apache2 is NOT running.
```

And when you query apache2ctl for its status, it hangs.

```
root@titan:~# /usr/sbin/apache2ctl status
**hangs until Ctrl-C is pressed.
```

So Ubuntu seems to be having trouble managing apache2 on bootup.  Time to stop apache2:

```
root@titan:~# /usr/sbin/apache2ctl stop
httpd (no pid file) not running
```

A big clue!  You try to stop apache2 and it lost the process id!  So Ubuntu can't stop apache2 because it doesn't know where it is!

You would think a reboot would fix it, but it doesn't because apache2 starts on boot and hangs.  The normal boot process for apache2 is not working right.

### So How to fix it?

**I was able to fix this** by analyzing the `ps` command output.  Notice that the `ps` command tells us that that process was started by "/etc/rc2.d/S91apache2 start".

That is the offending program that needs a swift kick.

`/etc/rc2.d/S91apache2` is the symbolic link used to start apache2 for you when the computer starts.  For some reason it seems to be starting apache2 and then hangs.  So we'll have to tell it to not do that.

So go take a look at that `/etc/rc2.d/S91apache2`.

```
el@titan:/etc/rc2.d$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    17 Nov  7 21:45 S91apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2*
```

It's a symbolic link that we don't want it to be there.  Do this to prevent apache2 from starting on boot:

```
root@titan:~# sudo update-rc.d -f apache2 remove
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/apache2 ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K09apache2
   /etc/rc1.d/K09apache2
   /etc/rc2.d/S91apache2
   /etc/rc3.d/S91apache2
   /etc/rc4.d/S91apache2
   /etc/rc5.d/S91apache2
   /etc/rc6.d/K09apache2
```

Reboot the computer to make sure apache2 doesn't start and hang.  Ok good.  Now you COULD put apache2 back the way it was, but that would make it fail again.

```
root@titan:~$ sudo update-rc.d apache2 defaults     //(don't do this)
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/apache2 ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
   /etc/rc1.d/K20apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
   /etc/rc6.d/K20apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
   /etc/rc2.d/S20apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
   /etc/rc3.d/S20apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
   /etc/rc4.d/S20apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
   /etc/rc5.d/S20apache2 -> ../init.d/apache2
```

Instead, start the apache2 like this:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

And the apache2 is back up and serving pages again.  There seems to be some serious bugs with apache2/Ubuntu 12.10 that causes apache2 to start and hang.  This is a workaround, I suppose the fix is to get newer versions of apache2 and Ubuntu and hope for the best.

Comment: Enjoyed reading and using your tips! Thanks for writing 'the way you debugged it'!

Comment: great instruction, man! Helped a lot, especially that you really described your way of troubleshooting!

Answer (score 13):

When I had this problem, it turned out to be because my Apache couldn't start on boot because I had an SSL site that required a password to be entered for the certificate.

A good way to tell whether this is the case for you is to run a `ps -ef | grep apache`: if this returns processes that look like `/bin/bash /usr/share/apache2/ask-for-passphrase mysite.com:443 RSA` then it's waiting for a password to be entered in a terminal that you will never see.

First, I killed the hung process (sending a `kill -HUP` to the process ID for /usr/sbin/apache2 process should be enough to kill the other ones too, but do another `ps -ef | grep apache` to be sure).

Then I followed the instructions [in this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63924/apache-boot-without-asking-for-passwd) to create an SSL password file that didn't require a password to be entered. Then a `service apache2 start` worked fine, and Apache started properly after a reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Not just duplicate mentions of

```
Listen 80
```

but also mention of this in addition to Listen 80

```
Include ports.conf
```

Comment: Yep this was the problem for me.. Remember to check the sites-available/ files *and* ports.conf

Answer (score 2):

This means you're port 80 is already being used, either change the port for apache2 (which I don't recommend) by editing:

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

Or close the application running on port 80:

```
netstat -antp | grep 80
```

To find what is running on port 80.

Comment: `netstat -antp | grep 80` outputs nothing as well.

Comment: can you copy and paste your output of netstat -antp | grep 80?

Comment: There is literally no output.

Comment: hmm that's odd, try changing the port to 81 if not it's not the port being blocked there's another error you can check apache2 errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint for anyone, who perhaps is running VirtualBox with NAT networks. I found, having a NAT rule between my guest and host had set itself up, binding the port

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't determine what my problem was.
There were no duplicates for listening on port 80 with `grep -ri listen /etc/apache2` and I could see no other application using port 80 with `netstat`.

I'm running a website with a certificate installed and so eventually I figured I don't necessarily need to listen on port 80, so I just deleted `Listen 80` line in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo service apache2 stop`
And Restart Apach  again

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem exactly after a reboot and spending hours to debug none of above answers could solve my apaches startup error.. There was no error description in logs.. Port 80 and 443 was not in use.. No duplicate `Listen` directives.. and totally not any clues to show me why apache is not working as expected after reboot!

I even tried running apaches startup debugger:

```
# For My CentOS 7:
httpd -e warn -E /var/log/my-custom-apache-debugging.log

# For Ubunto as asked in question:
apache -e debug -E /var/log/my-custom-apache-debugging.log
```

But No chance!..

Finally I remembered that I enabled selinux on my last modifications some weeks ago and never reboot after that change.
**`Disabling Selinux`** again and a final reboot solved this on my case.