# how to netstat and kill pid of the program to make server working?

Tags: 14.04, apache2

Our server [ **ubuntu 14.04** ] not working, so when i tried : **sudo service apache2 restart**, i got :

[image]

then when i tried **grep -ri listen /etc/apache2** , i got

[image]

As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277162/apache-fails-to-start-address-already-in-use-but-not-really) , i tried **netstat -ltnp | grep :80** , i got :

[image]

**edit**

**/etc/apache2/ports.cnf** :

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I am not getting what next thing i need to do ?

Comment: Please don't post images of text, instead copy the text and use the formatting tools to make it easy for reading.

Comment: @pa4080 i am sorry, i thought image will give better view. i will edit the question, please help me for this......

Comment: In some cases images are useful, but not in this one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `nginx` is listening to port `80`,you should stop `nginx` with this command `sudo service nginx stop`and start apache after.

Edit: after short discussion we figured out the problem was in: wrong config in `/etc/hosts` and running nginx server. everything fixed after moving apache to another port and adding correct hostname in `hosts` file.

Comment: thanks , i got : `nginx: unrecognized service
`

Comment: Check this out https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-restart-ubuntu-linux-command/

Comment: we didt installed nginx, we used only apache.....

Comment: From last picture you gave it clearly shows that port 80 is taken by nginx

Comment: oh, sorry, i dont have much idea about server as i am developer, i will check the link you gave....

Comment: If this won't be a production server and will be used only for development you can easy change the port of apache to 8888 and use it that way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69424/discussion-between-spylh9999ggr-and-asenm).

Answer (score 1):

Into the report of `sudo service apache2 restart` I can see two problems. 
The first one is the message `sudo: unable to resolve host <host-name>`. Probably the solution of that is here: [When I run a sudo command it says unable to resolve host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811098/when-i-run-a-sudo-command-it-says-unable-to-resolve-host/811113#811113).

The second one as @AsenM [noticed](https://askubuntu.com/a/981340/566421) is that some other service (nginx) is listen to the port `80`: `make_sock: could not bind to address: ...:80`. Usually you can use the command `sudo lsof -i -n -P` to investigate which service on which port listen.